# Beans defined with @Bean behave differently in Autowiring compared to beans defined with xml or @Component

Tags: spring, autowired, spring-java-config

I'm using Spring 4.1.5. Beans defined with @Bean act strange. Basically I am having problems Autowiring those beans when the dependency type is different from what is defined in the @Bean method signature.

For example if I define a @Bean with its interface type (MessageService) then I cannot autowire it in another dependent bean with its implementation type (MessageServiceImpl) (I am not putting proxies in the picture). Not even with the type of another interface that it happens to implement. These scenarios work as expected when the bean is defined in xml or with @Component. Here is the code:

**Main interface**

```
package hello.annotations;

public interface MessageService {
    String getMessage();
}
```

**Secondary interface**

```
package hello.annotations;

public interface AnotherInterface {
    boolean anotherMethod();
}
```

**Implementation**

```
package hello.annotations;

public class MessageServiceImpl implements MessageService, AnotherInterface {
    public String getMessage() {
        return "my msg";
    }

    public boolean anotherMethod() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Dependent bean**

```
package hello.annotations;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

public class MessagePrinter {

    @Autowired
    private MessageServiceImpl service1;

    @Autowired
    private AnotherInterface service2;

    @Autowired
    private MessageService service;

    public void printMessage() {
        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(service));
        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(service1));
        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(service2));
        System.out.println(this.service.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**Application**

```
package hello.annotations;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class Application {

    @Bean
    MessageService mockMessageService() {
        return new MessageServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    MessagePrinter messagePrinter() {
        return new MessagePrinter();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
        MessagePrinter printer = context.getBean(MessagePrinter.class);
        printer.printMessage();
    }
}
```

So you can see that in MessagePrinter, I am trying to inject the MessageServiceImpl with various ways: as a MessageService interface, as a MessageServiceImpl, and as an AnotherInterface.

I would say that this code doesn't work and it throws this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private hello.annotations.MessageServiceImpl hello.annotations.MessagePrinter.service1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [hello.annotations.MessageServiceImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [hello.annotations.MessageServiceImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 14 more{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

But here is where it gets even stranger: I just noticed that this is not deterministic. Sometimes it works. Run it 5-6 times you should notice it work sometimes. And another observation: If I change the order of the dependency fields in MessagePrinter putting the

```
 @Autowired private MessageService service;
```

first, then I think it always works. At least as many times as I have run it.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

**EDIT:** I am thinking that in order to simulate the exact behavior of xml and @Component you have to declare the return type of the @Bean method to be the implementation type. Let me know if I am wrong, but it looks like there is no downside to always declaring @Beans this way. The @Bean can still be overridden by another @Bean with the same method name and different return type.

Thanks and sorry for the long post.

Comment: I agree that there is no downside doing so. But it is even better starting with declaring dependencies when autowiring as interfaces when possible.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question. In fact I will only post what I assume, not being aware of the very details of spring autowiring.

First let's take for granted that spring builds a table of bean definitions before injecting dependencies. This table includes metadata such as the bean name and type. When the table is complete, then the DI takes place.

When you define your beans in xml, you set the class name of the target bean. This is the implementation class. Similarly when using @Component you set it at the implementation class declaration as well. This is the type registered for those bean definitions in the table. However when using @Bean and return an interface type, spring registers the bean with this interface type.

During the DI process, when @Autowired is encountered, spring tries to resolve towards the bean table using type information. When @Autowire requires an interface, spring happily matches interface or implementation definitions from the table. However when @Autowire requires an implementation type and there is only the interface type available, then the dependency cannot be resolved since the table information is more abstract.

Now, in your MessagePrinter class you are actually injecting the same bean three times.  If spring manages to resolve it once, possibly updates the bean definition type metadata with the implementation type. So the second time it knows more than the first and the wiring succeeds.  It seems from your observations that the order of the DI is indeed non deterministic but the declaration order is favored most of the times. I wouldn't say so if you had said that it never worked with the implementation declaration first.

If anyone is more aware of spring internals and can provide a more factual explanation, I am also very curious to know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Interesting thoughts. I am thinking now that in order to simulate the exact behavior of xml and \@Component you have to declare the return type of the \@Bean method to be the implementation type. I might be wrong, but it looks like there is no downside to always declaring \@Beans this way. The \@Bean can still be overridden by another \@Bean with the same method name and different return type. I am editing the original post to put this thought as well.